# Toggle display-state with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to toggle the visibility of a div with CSS through jQuery, but there seems to be something preventing this to work. The div contains a google map that I'm also initializing, but I really don't think that's the problem.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wh2n47s/)

### JavaScript:

```
function initialize() {
    var map;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
}

$( "#show-map" ).click(function() {
    $(".display-toggle").css("display", "block");
    initialize();
});

$( "#hide-map" ).click(function() {
    $(".display-toggle").css("display", "none");
});
```

### CSS:

```
#map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.my-map-section {
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

.display-toggle {
    display: none;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div>
    <form id="myform">
        <input id="show-map" type="button" value="Show map"></input>
        <input id="hide-map" type="button" value="Hide map"></input>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="section my-map-section display-toggle">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The click event codes should be in `$(document).ready(function(){})` function.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal not necessarily. It's the best practice, but it can be anywhere after the respective elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your clickhandlers inside a document.ready handler
See updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9wh2n47s/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#show-map" ).click(function() {
        $(".display-toggle").css("display", "block");
        initialize();
    });

    $( "#hide-map" ).click(function() {
        $(".display-toggle").css("display", "none");
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your html Slightly to add an Id to the section you are showing and hiding / removing some extra classes:

```
<div>
    <form id="myform">
        <input id="show-map" type="button" value="Show map"></input>
        <input id="hide-map" type="button" value="Hide map"></input>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="map-section" class="section my-map-section">
    <p>There is something else here</p>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
```

With an update to your css, to hide it by default :

```
#map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.my-map-section {
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And then wrapping your javascript in a document ready tag, and changing the jquery to use show / hide (Which is the same as setting the css classes)

```
function initialize(maplocation) {
    var map;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(maplocation, mapOptions);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show-map").click(function () {
        $("#map-section").show();
        initialize(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
    });

    $("#hide-map").click(function () {
        $("#map-section").hide();
    });
});
```

Hope that gives you a clear picture. : http://jsfiddle.net/yevcccyL/1/

Comment: Thanks – that seems like a more elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to toggle the element without the need to write the css yourself. This option will allow you to just use one button instead of two.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#show-map" ).click(function() {
        console.log("test");
        $(".display-toggle").toggle();
        initialize();
    });

});
```

However if you want to have teo buttons you could just use jquery `show()` and `hide()` on each buton. Again removing the need to write css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#show-map" ).click(function() {
        console.log("test");
        $(".display-toggle").toggle();
        initialize();
    });

    $( "#hide-map" ).click(function() {
        console.log("test2");
        $(".display-toggle").hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: I was asking for the CSS-solution because I might want to add more CSS with the buttons, but thanks, that's helpful nonetheless.

Comment: No worries, just trying to give you options.